# ad obsidionem urbis vs. ad obsidendam urbem

Tags: classical-latin, syntax, gerundive, predicate

I was wondering to what extent the two Prepositional Phrases (PPs) in the title of the present question can be taken as functionally equivalent. Consider the following text about Caesar's siege of Massilia:

> [Massilienses] reliquas merces commeatusque **ad obsidionem urbis**, si accidat, reservant. Quibus iniuriis permotus Caesar legiones tres Massiliam adducit; turres vineasque **ad oppugnationem urbis** agere, naves longas Arelate numero XII facere instituit.  (Caes. *Civ.* 1.36)

It seems clear that in this text the PP *ad oppugnationem urbis* could be easily replaced by the PP *ad oppugnandam urbem*. In contrast, the previous PP *ad obsidionem urbis* cannot be replaced by the PP *ad obsidendam urbem*, since the intepretation would be that the Massilians were the agents of the siege of their own city! (Note that, grammatically speaking, this infelicitous reading is not excluded in one of the readings of *ad obsidionem urbis*). Any thoughts on the grammatical explanation of this contrast?

Comment: I recently reread the BC, this time with a private student, and I remember discussing this very point: the fact that the sentences *appear* to be using a parallel construction to 'mark' a contrast, as Cicero might do, but it's deceptive – the parallelism is only surface-deep. There's still a little note about this in the margin of my OCT. I also have a recollection that this isn't the only place where Caesar does such a thing. In a way, it's the opposite of Sallustian-style inconcinnity, where difference in surface appearance belies similarity in underlying meaning. It's a great question.

Comment: @cnread Many thanks for your comment!

Comment: @cnread: Please, "BC"...Back Catalogue (?) & "OCT"?

Comment: @Mitomino: Given that "ad oppugnationem urbis agere" = "to arrange for the attacking of the city"; "ad obsidionem urbis" = "for a siege of the city"; "ad obsidendam urbem" = "for the purpose of besieging the city"; these display clear differences e.g. use of "ad"= "for purpose of". And on the ground: an attack tends to be quick, hopefully, whereas a siege can last for years (Leningrad). What exactly are you looking for, here?

Comment: @tony, BC = Bellum Civile, OCT = Oxford Classical Text

Comment: @tony I was wondering why it's the case that in the text above "the PP _ad oppugnationem urbis_ could be easily replaced by the PP _ad oppugnandam urbem_. In contrast, the previous PP _ad obsidionem urbis_ cannot be replaced by the PP _ad obsidendam urbem_". Are you suggesting that this contrast could be due to the polysemy of the preposition _ad_?

Comment: @Mitomino: It seemed to be fatuous, if not patronising, to attempt to explain the nuanced differences between these (similar) expressions. Hence the assumption that yourself was looking for something deeper, that I could not see. The answer, in the Q., construction "ad + gerundive" ("ad obsidiendum urbem") implying that the Massilians might besiege their own city, precludes its use. The interpretation of cnread's reversal of Sallust: similarity in surface appearance belies (fundamental) difference in underlying meaning. With the constructions "ad + gerund/ + gerundive: how does the student

Comment: @Mitomino: recognise which one it is? Given that the meaning is the same "for the purpose of..." does it matter?

Comment: @tony The _general_ question here has to do with the differences between verbal nouns with suffix _-tio_ and verbal adjectives (gerundives). Since both nominal forms are derived from verbs, one could expect a similarity as for the interpretation of the arguments inherited from their corresponding verbs (NB: both forms involve an agent and a patient) but it is not always the case: for example, note that in the text above _ad oppugnationem urbis_ **can** indeed be replaced by _ad oppugnandam urbem_  but _ad obsidionem urbis_ **cannot** be replaced by _ad obsidendam urbem_. **Why?**